# How to select(check) with a keyboard methods in Override/Implement methods dialog in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to select(check) with a keyboard desired methods in Override/Implement methods dialog box in Eclipse Juno (4.2) running on Ubuntu 12.04 and can't select any of them. If I left-click on the check box with the mouse the method get checked. Can I do this with a key stroke?

[image]

EDIT: with a lot of try/error, just found the keyboard shortcut for this operation:
Shift + Space
and the method on focus get checked(selected)

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer

Comment: yep, sorry I'll post it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

just found it - this is the default keyboard shortcut for that operation